# How do I save some lines but not all?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

In Terminal how do I save lines 3, 4 and 5 from an existing file to a new file in a single command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is `sed`. See [*How to print particular line number by using sed command*](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/08/08/print-particular-line-number-using-sed-command/), for example:

```
sed -n '3,5 p' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

By default, `sed` prints all lines it encounters, so we suppress that with the `-n` switch and then select the lines `3` to `5` for `p`rinting.

There are numerous other ways (e.g. `awk`) and I'm pretty sure there will be more answers soon to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

For lines that are not in continuation:

```
sed -n -e 2p -e 4p -e 6p < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: You can also just use semicolons to separate `sed` commands: `sed -n '2p;4p;6p' file > new`